# Prettier removes "React" import on pressing save button ( Ctrl + S ). How to fix this?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

On pressing `CTRL + S` , prettier removes `React` import from tsx files, assuming its not used in the file.

How to fix this ?

[image: Issue]

Comment: Mine also started doing this in the last couple days... Did you find a fix for it?

Comment: @MarcodaFonseca Yes, same here. Only recently i face this issue. All i remember was updating VS CODE recenlty. Couldn't find a fix for it. Not sure whats causing it.

Comment: @MarcodaFonseca found the fix.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My `tsconfig.json` had the following settings:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "jsx": "preserve"
   }
}
```

Changing `jsx` value from `preserve` to `react` solved the issue.

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "jsx": "react"
   }
}
```

Reference : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/152150#issuecomment-1156717872

Comment: Mine was `"jsx": "react-jsx"`. Changing it to `"jsx": "react"` worked. Thanks

Comment: @HristoEnev I had the same problem. Weird how it didn't used to be a problem until recently.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using prettier then add this property to `.prettierrc`

```
organizeImportsSkipDestructiveCodeActions: true,
```

this helped me
also can use this plugin for managing imports

```
npm i prettier-plugin-organize-imports
```

read more [here](https://yarnpkg.com/package/prettier-plugin-organize-imports)